# Why does this function not fail immediately?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following piece of code. `main` gets the `stdin` text and sequences it through `g`, after which `f` prints it's output and returns an appropriate `ExitCode` which is commited using `exitWith`.

My question is why does this program, when run with the sample input, not terminate immediately after the first line (`test`) is entered, but only fails after it reads the second line (`test2`)? What I want to happen is for the `g` function to return immediately after `parse1` returns `Left "left: test"` and not wait until the second line is entered.

Code:

```
import System.Exit
import Control.Monad
import Data.Either

type ErrType = String

parse1 :: String -> Either ErrType Int
parse1 "test" = Left "left: test"
parse1 _ = Left "left"

parse2 :: String -> Either ErrType Char
parse2 s = Right (head s)

g :: String -> Either String String
g str =
  let l1:l2:ls = lines str
  in either (Left . show) (Right . show) $ do
    a <- parse1 l1
    b <- parse2 l2
    return "placeholder"

main = getContents >>= f.g >>= exitWith
  where f (Right s) = putStrLn s >> return ExitSuccess
        f (Left s) = putStrLn s >> return (ExitFailure 1)
```

Standard input stream:

```
test
test2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line

```
let l1:l2:ls = lines str
```

means that to evaluate even just `l1`, the *whole* pattern `l1:l2:ls` needs to match, which means that a check needs to be done that `str` actually contains at least two lines.  With lazy input, that causes the behavior you see.

You can fix it with an explicitly lazy pattern that defers the check for the second line:

```
let l1 : ~(l2:ls) = lines str
```

or, since a top pattern in a let is implicitly lazy, you could split it up like:

```
let l1:ls' = lines str
    l2:ls = ls'
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with the `~` syntax.